# Delete/Drop Machine Learning Models in Vertica if exists

Tags: machine-learning, models, vertica

Is it possible to check if a model exists before deleting it using `DELETE_MODEL`
I am trying to avoid getting an error message while trying to delete a model that is not yet created. Basiscally I am looking for counterpart of: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` but for models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you check for its existence from vsql:

```
sbx_marco=> \x
Expanded display is on.
sbx_marco=> select * from models where model_name ilike 'logisticRegModel';
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------------------------------------------
schema_name    | public
model_owner    | dbadmin
category       | Vertica_Models
model_name     | logisticregmodel
model_type     | logistic regression
format_version | Vertica Analytic Database v8.0.0-20160801
mode_size      | 996
deploy_time    | 2016-08-24 13:59:14.01-04
```

So it will be about creating a script that, for example, counts the models with a given name -and a given owner, and if the count is 0, does not do anything, otherwise deletes the model ...

A WHERE condition?

Comment: Wow, this is more complicated than I thought, but I guess
`SELECT * FROM models` Will do the trick. Thanks